# Question 11 of Chapter 7 in do Carmo’s Riemannian Geometry: is the integral curve defined for all $t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

The prompt is as follows. Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold, and $X$ a smooth vector field on $M$ such that for all $p$ in $M$, $|X(p)| > c > 0$ for some constant $c$. Recall that the flow curve $\phi : (-T, T) \to M$ of $X$ based at $q \in M$ is defined by the differential equation $\phi '(t) = X(\phi (t))$ and $\phi(0) = q$. Show that the flow curve is defined for any $T > 0$.

After thinking about it for a while this seems false to me. For instance, let $f: (-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be any monotone increasing smooth bijection, so that $f'$ is bounded below by a positive constant (for instance, $f(t) = \textrm{tan}(\pi t)$). Here $\mathbb{R}$ has the Euclidean metric, and is complete.

Then defining a vector field $Y$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by $Y(x) = f'(f^{-1}(x))$, we see that $Y$ satisfies the hypothesis, and $f$ is the flow curve of $Y$ based at $f(0)$. But $\lim\limits_{t \to 1} f(t) = \infty$, and $\lim\limits_{t \to -1} f(t) = -\infty$, so the curve is only defined on $(-1, 1)$ and cannot be extended.

Of course, were the inequality in the hypothesis reversed, so that $|X(p)| < c$ for all $p$, the statement would be easy to prove. Have I made a mistake?

Comment: You are right and the statement is false.